# spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring

When I use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in my war , I get the below error

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'systemProperties[''mySystemProperty']
```

wherever I am trying to access systemproperties.

If I remove the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`  it works fine.

Is there any way we can use both `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`  and `systemProperties` together?

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is wrong. Use

```
systemProperties['mySystemProperty']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question . I got confused using $ instead of # for sytemProperties